# Regex username for codeigniter route

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I am trying to get my regex to not allow the following words:

- create
- Forum

I also would like to allow only 1 underscore..

Here is what I have so far:

```
$route['(^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{3,20}+$)'] = "users/index";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the routes you don't want to match before that one (it will stop at the first matched route):

```
$route['create(/.*)?'] = "create$1";
$route['forum(/.*)?']  = "forum$1";
$route['(^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{3,20}+$)'] = "users/index";
```

Comment: Yea i was trying to avoid having to create a route for each page... as it is said it should be avoided if possible...

Comment: Regexs are those funny cases where we get pretty target fixated to "figure it out."  I probably would have spent a full day on it just to avoid giving up. Haha. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, this is the closest I can get:

```
^((?:(?!create|Forum)[A-Za-z0-9]){3,20})$
```

[Example](http://rubular.com/r/6wlcag1pj1)

Gotta leave now. Good luck with this!

Comment: Thanks for sharing that url to the regex website... wish I would have known about that site before... it helps with testing regex's

Comment: Sure. Actually, take a look at my profile and you'll find more handy URLS :)